# Access a variable in a function from another module?

Tags: python, import, module

Two .py files, the `to_be_imported.py` has:

```
def func(a):

    b = a + "!!!"
    c = b + " Mike!!!"
    print c
```

The `import.py` has:

```
from to_be_imported import *
func("hey")
```

But when I try to access variable `b` I got error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'b'.`.

How to get the value of `b` after I give the function value `"hey"`?

Comment: please post the error. We cant do anything with `I got error `

Comment: You should read about local and global variables in Python https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python

Comment: Your posted code has no reference to a remote symbol **b**; the code does not show the error you describe.

Comment: `func` returns `None`, since you don't have an explicite `return` statement. This, when you assign `var = func('hey')`, then `var == None` and when you try `var.b` you'll get the error you are seeing. Furthermore, even if `var` was *not* `None`, you can't access the local variables in `func` that way, unless you do some hocus-pocus with `locals()` and return that... but that sounds like a fundamental design issue with your code. In general, if you want some value inside some function, your function should *return that value*.

Comment: You can only access top-level module variables (aka module globals) from another script/module. You can never access the local variables of a function outside the function unless they are the or one of the return values of the function. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-the-scoping-rules/292502#292502) to a question about Python's scoping rules.

Answer (score 1):

**to_be_imported** does *not* have a variable **b**.  The only **b** in your program is local to **func**, and disappears when you exit the function.  The canonical way to do this would be:

```
def func(a):

    b = a + "!!!"
    c = b + " Mike!!!"
    print c
    return b

...

from to_be_imported import *
local_b = func("hey")
```

There are other ways to do this.  For instance, you could be make **b** a global variable of **to_be_imported** and then access it with something like

```
print to_be_imported.b
```

However, this is generally not a good idea.  Also, note that it's not really a good idea to have a remote function both print output and return a value.  Modules and passing information are really cool, but make sure you follow recommendations in the textbook or tutorials you're using, so you don't have debugging troubles later.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider returning the value, like in this example:

```
def add_one(numb):
    """Given a number, add one and return it."""
    r = numb +1
    return r
```

Also note that it's generally bad practice to do `from module import *`, as it can overwrite functions in the module that does that import.
You might try importing just what you need, like: `from mymodule import func, func_two, func_three`